# MS SQL DATEDIFF on max of two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I would like to select the latest date that is more than a day old. I have two date type columns. Column1 will be the default (nonnull), if column2 is not null then it will always be greater than column1.

I currently have

```
select * from table where 0<(DATEDIFF(day, column1, getdate())
```

Of course this only returns based on column1.

How would I be able to implement the use of column2 if it is not null?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISNULL(column2, column1)` to return the first non-null value in the where part of your query.

So if column2 is not null, it'll return that - otherwise if it is null - it'll return 1

Answer (score 0):

You could use `coalesce` to return the first non-null column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table 
WHERE  0 < (DATEDIFF(DAY, COALESCE(column2, column1), getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing comparisons in the `where` clause on dates, it is best to not use functions on columns.  This generally prevents indexes from being used.

If you want the latest date that is more than a day old, perhaps this is what you want.  This query will order the rows by the most recent date more than a day old at the top:

```
select *
from table
order by (case when column2 < getdate() - 1 then column2
               when column1 < getdate() - 1 then column1
               else '0000-00-00'
          end) desc;
```

Use `top 1` to get the most recent.